# Can I use a middle ware proxy to redirect or route from localhost url to another

Tags: javascript, http, frontend

I have two separate apps that comprise one app. One is written in Angular another in react, we are strangling off the Angular app. These two talk to each other on the server using `<ReverseProxy and <Proxy` - I believe this is nginx? Regardless, locally they don't talk at all, and I'm trying to use node, particularly I think I want http-proxy-middleware library.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I want the proxy to pick up localhost:3100/overview to instead be rewritten or redirected to localhost:9001/overview so my other server running can pick it up.

I've tried using http-proxy, and http-proxy-middleware node libraries, I maybe looked at spinning up another express server but I think these libraries will do what I want.

```
var express = require("express");
var proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

var app = express();

app.use(
  "/",
  proxy({
    target: "http://localhost:3100",
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true,
    router: {
      "/overview": "http://localhost:9001"
    }
  })
);
app.listen(300);
```

This does nothing.

the localhost:3100/overview url in browser will change to localhost:9001/overview.

Comment: why don't you spin up nginx locally (potentially in a docker image)?

Comment: @RuneFS well, that's a possibility, I've considered it. But I find that solution to be more robust.  I thought node would be the cleanest, simplest solution.

Comment: it's generally a good idea to have a local environment build on the same building blocks as the production environment. That is essential to DevOps